# Customize Table View on More Tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to customize the look of the table view associated with the more tab of a tab bar?  I'm wanting to set a cell background image and customize the text for each cell.  I've found info about working with the navigation bar for the more view but can't seem to find anything about customizing its table view.

[image]

Comment: you can fully customise view of a tableView but from your question I can not get the issue of the problem

Comment: I know how to customize table views.  I'm trying to figure out how to customize the table view for the more tab of a tab bar that gets created once more than five tabs are added.

Comment: @user2029585 what is more tab of a tab bar? Please expand on what exactly you are trying to achieve, chances are there probably is a better and efficient way to do it.

Comment: The "more" tab is added automatically once you add more than five items to a tab bar.  When you select this tab it takes you to a table view with the tabs you've added that won't fit on the tab bar.

Comment: @Pavan, maybe you should read up on UITabBarController...

Comment: @Mundi Hi mundi, I probably should. In my efforts to help however, I needed to understand what he meant by 'more tab of a tab bar' since as you may have noticed, it's been a while since i've taken a look at tabbars. I do understand now what he meant by the `more tab of a tab bar` after having looked at his picture. You could have simply cleared it up instead of being rude about it.

Comment: @Pavan sorry, I did not mean to be rude. I appreciate your sincere effort of trying to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it to some extent, [as explained in my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uitabbar). Start with the UITabBarController's `moreNavigationController`. Through it, you can access the root view controller: it is the first item in the UINavigationController's `viewControllers` array. And through that, you can access the table view: it is the root view controller's `view`.

The problem, however, is that the table view has a data source and a delegate, and you are not either of them - and you don't want to subvert what they do. In my book (see link above), I show how to insert your own data source in between the table view and the built-in data source, but what you can accomplish this way is limited, and it works differently in different systems (e.g. iOS 6 vs. iOS 7). Thus, for example, my book shows how (in iOS 6) you can change the font of the cells and eliminate the accessory detail chevron at the right end of the cells.

See also my downloadable example code (in this case, you would want to look at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch12p611tabBarMore).

Comment: That explanation in your book is quite amazing!  I'll be using it in my app. Gave you a few more ^ on other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea, but I have not tried it:

The `UITabBarController` has a property `moreNavigationController`, which is a plain `UINavigationController`. Unfortunately it is `readonly`, so subclassing won't help, but you can most likely still manipulate it by setting a different `topViewController`.

This seems worth a try. Let us know if it works.